# How do I do a string comparison when the string I'm comparing has symbols?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pull in data from a text file that's been set up in a makeshift custom XML format:

```
<question>
    <question_text>What should you do with your work when traveling?</question_text>
    <answer_correct>Keep it in somewhere locked and out of view</answer_correct>
    <answer_incorrect>Put it in the back seat so it's off your mind</answer_incorrect>
    <answer_incorrect>Put it in the front seat so it's easy to access</answer_incorrect>
    <answer_incorrect>Throw it out the window</answer_incorrect>
    <reason><p>PCWorld reported in 2014 that 31% of breaches are due to lost or stolen devices.  Hiding or locking away confidential materials and equipment is the best solution to prevent loss or theft.</p></reason>
</question>
```

I'm able to get the data parsed properly in JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/bhwxp4Lb/2/:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i] == "<question>"){
        i++;
        a = "<question_text>";
        b = data[i];
        questions.push(b.substr(a.length,(b.length - (a.length+1))));
        i++;
        a = "<answer_correct>";
        b = data[i];
        answerText.push(b.substr(a.length,(b.length - (a.length+1))));
        i++;
        a = "<answer_incorrect>";
        b = data[i];
        answerText.push(b.substr(a.length,(b.length - (a.length+1))));
        i++;
        a = "<answer_incorrect>";
        b = data[i];
        answerText.push(b.substr(a.length,(b.length - (a.length+1))));
        i++;
        a = "<answer_incorrect>";
        b = data[i];
        answerText.push(b.substr(a.length,(b.length - (a.length+1))));
        i++;
        a = "<reason>";
        b = data[i];
        reasons.push(b.substr(a.length,(b.length - (a.length+1))));
        i++;
        answers.push(answerText);
    }
}
```

However, it won't work properly on my local environment.  I'm assuming it has to do something with the `less than` (<) and `greater than` (>) symbols in the strings; for example: `if(data[I] == <question>)` works as expected in JSFIDDLE, but not on my local system.  Does anyone know how to get around this issue?  Am I doing this properly?  Is there a better way? How do I do a string comparison when the string I'm comparing has symbols?

Comment: That fiddle isn’t what I’d call “working”. Where does `data` come from? Also, use real XML and a real XML parser, or better, JSON.

Comment: You can use jQuery.parseXML() for more friendly xml parsing: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I got it using https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/